# Getting "Not permitted" as a cause while creating a listener for TIBCO JMS Topic

Tags: spring, listener, jms-topic, tibco-topic

While setting up a JMS listener for a TIBCO topic using Spring, I am getting the below error as our TIBCO won't allow any other subscribers. So, I am looking for any alternative solution to consume the messages that are sent to that TIBCO topic.

"Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'TIBCO_JMS_TOPIC_NAME' - trying to recover. **Cause: Not permitted**"

NOTE: I gone through the answer for the related question which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212194/use-spring-integration-dsl-to-read-from-tibco-ems-topic) and I don't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might be facing a permission issue. You need to check with your EMS administrator if the management of ACLs on topics has been enabled and if the user you are using to connect to your EMS has the right to subscribe to your target topic.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your EMS user has "durable" permission for the topic. I have faced the same issue and was able to resolve it by giving durable permission to the user.